# RDP through NAT

Tags: kvm-virtualization, nat, rdp

I've got a VDS with Centos 7.6, there is a KVM, and 1 VM with Win10. Both can see internet and each other, everything was set up with default NAT. Now i want to be able to RDP to windows by mstsc to VDS by some port.

Three days of fighting with manuals gave nothing. current config looks like:

```
[root@static etc]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s31f6
  sources: 
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client vnc-server
  ports: 3389/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: port=3389:proto=tcp:toport=3389:toaddr=192.168.122.10
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

which seems to be correct. i do feel that this is a stupid and prolly a trivial question, but have no clue where to move further.

Any ideas, please?

UPD. more details to make it more clear.

Host configuration (No bridge, only NAT, 1 physical interface):

```
[root@static ~]# ifconfig enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 95.217.38.211  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 95.217.38.255
        inet6 fe80::4e52:62ff:fe0b:9bee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 4c:52:62:0b:9b:ee  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 9459  bytes 1506084 (1.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9368  bytes 5002008 (4.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xef200000-ef220000
```

Client configuration:

```
DHCP: no
IPv4: 192.168.121.10
MASK: 255.255.255.0
GATE: 192.168.122.1
DNS : 192.168.122.1
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The problem is that i want to forward RDP traffic from host (Centos) to guest (Win10).

Comment: Which interface/bridge/... has the IP address 192.168.122.1 configured?

Comment: this one: enp0s31f6. it's a main VDS, which has external ip and internal ip (*.122.1) which works as a gate for NAT.

Comment: That's not the problem, it's what you want to happen. Which appears to be what you've already set up. What is the actual problem that occurs when you try to RDP?

Comment: @Michael, obviously, the problem is that i can't connect. standard error message: remote machine is unavailable or server is down, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

When I run into these kinds of problems, I usually run tcpdump and/or wireshark to try and see what is happening.  I don't have the full details of your configuration, but I'll assume for a moment that you are using a Linux machine with a windows virtual machine running on the same hardware.

I would run Wireshark in Windows and set the capture options dialog to use `port 3389` as the capture filter.  This will restrict the captured traffic to only the RDP port.

Once that is running, I would do the same at the Linux command line, specifically targeting each interface, so 2 network cards or interfaces would require running two instances of tcpdump.  The command would be something like:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 -p port 3389 
# tcpdump -i eth1 -p port 3389
```

...assuming you have two network interfaces, either virtual or physical - you will have to substitute the correct interface name with the -i option.  If you only have one network interface, then you would only run one tcpdump instance.  If you don't have tcpdump, you may have to install it through your package manager.

Once all of the captures are active, try and connect via RDP and then check the output at each connection along the way.  Once you find where the connection is getting blocked or dropped, you then know where to focus your efforts.  You don't need to know a lot of networking to do this.

This has saved me a bunch of times.  One common issue is to have set the default gateway incorrectly on one of the machines.  An improper route can very easily look the same as a misconfigured firewall rule.

Comment: I always thought, that this stuff can be resolved by forwarding, without any additional magic. Am i wrong?

Comment: A port forward does take care of most of it.  But, check that your virtual windows machine has a correct default route.  I'm uncertain what happens if you leave that field blank and in the case of a NAT, the windows machine isn't just communicating locally; it will see the client address in the packets it receives and will try to respond to that address.